# Swift: A function amends value of variable, I want to use this variable elsewhere to update UI

Tags: ios, swift, function, alamofire

have been looking around for this answer it this. It feels basic, but i must be doing something wrong.

I have a function, which using Alamofire pulls in a JSON feed, parses it. I then want to use elements from this to update various labels in my UI.

```
func collectData(){


    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://xxxxxxxx.co.uk/xxxx.php")
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request

            if let JSONtest = response.result.value {

                let json = JSON(JSONtest)


                if let name = json[0]["Name"].string {

                }


            }
    }


}

collectData()

usernameLabel.text = name
```

Obviously, the function just runs, and within the function I can print((name)) or print((JSONtest)) and they both print as expected.   How do I use an updated variable from within the function elsewhere in my project.

If I put usernameLabel.text = name in the function, it works fine.

I can create the constant outside of the method, and outside of the class but this only affects the initial value, not the amended one.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

So i've discovered that this is happening because Alamofire and SwiftyJSON are asyncronous, and that only variables in the request will work. I've tried to put my code into the request. Some of it has worked, but it looks a bit of a mess.

Also, I want to pull a URL from the database and on a button click, goto that URL. I don't see how I can do that, as I can't have an IBAction in the request....

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Global Variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_382) is your solution. Create a global variable to hold the entire JSON response and then you can parse it to get your desired values from where ever within your class you want.

> Global variables are variables that are defined outside of any
>   function, method, closure, or type context.Global constants and
>   variables are always computed lazily

Comment: Hi there, yep I tried that, but due to Alamofire and SwiftyJSON being Asyncronous this doesn't seem to work... Any other ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable in top your class -before override func viewDidLoad()- like

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var nameFromJson:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
```

and then in your code

```
func collectData(){

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://xxxxxxxx.co.uk/xxxx.php")
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request

            if let JSONtest = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(JSONtest)
                if let name = json[0]["Name"].string {
                self.nameFromJson = name
                }
            }
    }
}

collectData()
usernameLabel.text = self.nameFromJson
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I've tried that. Xcode prompted me to make nameFromJson a var as opposed to a constant. I've done that, and the error I get now is "Class 'ViewController' has no initializers"

Comment: So i've initialised nameFromJson:String with ="" to get rid of that error. The app builds, but the text doesn't display...

Comment: Are you getting the name?  Before self.nameFromJson = name try a print(name) to see that you actually getting the name.

Comment: So if I do print((self.nameFromJson)) from within the function, it works perfectly. As soon as I do it outside the function it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

This might as well be the worst solution, but it works for me.

I pass the strings as `textfield.text`'s to use them in other places/functions. The textfields are background colour and hidden from the actual application UI (using storyboard), so that the user doesn't see the data.

Like I said - this may not be the most efficient or correct way, but it works for me.

```
func collectData() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://xxxxxxxx.co.uk/xxxx.php")
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  //Unnecessary

        if let JSONtest = response.result.value {
            let json = JSON(JSONtest)

            /* Store other values like this
            if let color = json[0]["Color"].string
                self.bogustextfield.text = color
            */

            if let name = json[0]["Name"].string {
                self.usernamelabel.text = name
            }
        }
    }
}
collectData()

//use them like this
/*
func(useAlamoVar) {
    let color = self.bogustextfield.text
    //turn "color" back into a variable
}
*/
```

Comment: @StephenRauch Is that what you meant by "format the code"? Thanks for the help!